# Forgot Mac password, don't have apple keyboard

Tags: password

I have forgotten my Apple Mac password. I have searched for multiple key codes to change the password but i haven't figured out how they work on a non-apple keyboard. I use a logitech (K120) keyboard.

Comment: What exactly have you tried to do (which doesn't seem to work with a non-apple keyboard)?

Comment: Do you have a firmware password enabled? If not, there is a way to change the password. Please also edit your question to mention your OS and model.

Comment: I would try booting with combinations of the (alt/option/windows/control/shift) and "r" keys until you hit the correct one. Note that keys on the left and right of the space bar might behave differently even if they are labeled the same.

Answer (score 1):

See this [link from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970299) on how to use a Windows keyboard on a Mac. It is very useful for this exact issue and helps me a lot at times. To boot into recovery with a Windows keyboard you will need to hold down Ctrl and R at the start chime.